# Define Absolute path to delete file from ftp server in php

Tags: php, file-io, ftp, sftp

I am using following code to delete file from ftp server. i have given ftp server as like given in below code. also give user name and password as shown in below.

```
$ftp_server = 'ftp://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.uk/test_folder/app';
$ftpuser = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$ftppass = 'xxxxxxxxx';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpuser, $ftppass);

// delete all files in the folder logs
    ftp_delete($conn_id, $string);

    // close the connection
        ftp_close($conn_id);
```

while I am running my code it shows me list of warnings as given below and doesn't delete file from ftp server.

> **Warning**:  ftp_connect() [function.ftp-connect]:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known in **/home/del/public_html/app/delr.php** on line
>   **24**
>  
>  **Warning**:  ftp_login() expects parameter
>   1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   **/home/del/public_html/app/delr.php** on line **27**
>   **Warning**:  ftp_delete() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in **/home/del/public_html/app/delr.php** on line
>   **30**
>  
>  **Warning**:  ftp_close() expects parameter
>   1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   **/home/del/public_html/app/delr.php** on line **33**

I think the way I am passing the ftp server url path, is wrong.
I have searched  a lot on net and in stackoverflow but not able to get proper solution.Can anybody show me the way or provide an example or anything to solve this.Please someone let me know that where I am going wrong.

Comment: Maybe DNS isn't working on your PHP server or you misspelled the FTP server name. Try to use the FTP server's IP address instead of the server name. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

ftp server should be either `xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.uk` or the `ip address` — **without `ftp://`**

```
$ftp_server =  'xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.uk';
```